# Want to know the exact value of requests waiting in HttpBeginRequest

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, performancecounter, newrelic

We run our application on `.Net Framework 2.0` and `IIS 7.5`

While checking in New Relic, we found that we take a lot of time in `System.Web.HttpApplication.BeginRequest()`.

We are working on that fact, i.e. trying to disable session on page level, on all those pages where it is not required.

But currently, We want to know how many total requests are waiting in `System.Web.HttpApplication.BeginRequest()`?

We saw in IIS Request Monitor, that there are a number of requests in `BeginRequest` at all particular times.

But is there a performance counter or some way thru code that I can know the exact value of such requests?

Answer (score 0):

You have ASP.Net\Requests Queued performance counter to check the number of the requests that are queued and are waiting to be serviced.
More info at: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fxk122b4%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Comment: I have already configured that, but it gives me value 0 everytime.

While, in the Request Monitor, I see a number of requests.

I doubt whether this performance counter would help me in this case